# AR query with multiple HABTM models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models: Project, Year, and Category

Project has a HABTM relationship with both years and categories.

I'm trying to get all projects that belong to both a given category and a given year.

Something like `Project.where("year.name = ? and category.name = ?", "2012", "print")` But I'm not sure how to do this with associated models rather than attributes of the model.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Project.joins(:years).joins(:categories).where("years.name = ? and categories.name = ?", "#{year}", "#{category}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit awkward, but it works:

```
Year.find_by_name("2012").projects.all(:include => :categories, :conditions => ["categories.name = ?", "print"])
```